# Smoothness of a map from an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Please take a look at the following picture and find the statement underlined with red. I'm curious about the meaning of "the usual sense". For your information, $\mathbb{H}^n$ denotes the closed $n$-dimensional upper half-space, that is,
$$\mathbb{H}^n=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_n\geq 0 \}.$$
To me, in order to talk about the smoothness of a function in the usual sense,  the domain of the function has to be an open subset of a Euclidean space. In view of this, I doubt that $U\cap\textrm{Int}\mathbb{H}^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why do you doubt that $U\cap\operatorname{Int}\mathbb{H}^n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true. Is the set we are talking about really open?

Comment: @Steve yes. $\text{ Int } \mathbb{H}^n$ is the set where $x_n > 0$, which is open, so this is an intersection of two opens

Comment: How about $U$? It is merely relatively open in $\mathbb{H}^n$.

Comment: If $U$ is open in $\mathbb{H}^n$, then $U\cap\operatorname{Int}\mathbb{H}^n$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Try proving this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have been trying to do.

Comment: @Steve map $U \to \mathbb{R}$ by projecting to the $n$th coordinate. Then $U \cap \mathbb{H}^n$ is the inverse image of the open set of positive numbers.

Comment: I posted my answer. Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry about being silly. If $U$ is relatively open in $\mathbb{H}^n$, there exists an open subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $U=A\cap\mathbb{H}^n$. By using the fact that the upper half-space is a disjoint union of its boundary and interior, one can see that $U\cap\textrm{Int}\mathbb{H}^n=A\cap\textrm{Int}\mathbb{H}^n$, which is obviously an open set in the Euclidean space.